# Returning Then as Undefined. Q in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I am trying to return values from my REST request and in the success handler I am returning all the values as a deferred promise but when i run the `landingPage` function I can't resolve the deferred promise. It gives me `.then` is `undefined`. I am using Unirest library for HTTP requests and Q for Promises.

Is it because the `return` in the request callback returned the data earlier before the server could fetch the data and hence it didn't returned the `deferred` object or it is something else.

Below is the code:

```
var landingPage = function (dir) {
    Uni.get('https://'+getDirectory(dir).url)
        .header('Content-Type','text/html')
        .end(function (lp_data) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            if (lp_data.raw_body) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(lp_data.raw_body),
                    cn_europe = $('#location_europe .list-countries li'),
                    cn_asia = $('#content-location_asia_pacific li'),
                    cn_north_america = $('#content-location_north_america li');

                // Get Europe Company List
                var europe = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < cn_europe.length; i++) {
                    var country_name = $(cn_europe[i]).find('a').html().split('(')[0].trim(),
                        esomar_url = 'https://' + getDirectory(dir).url + '/' + $(cn_europe[i]).find('a').attr('href');
                    europe.push({country_name: country_name, esomar_url: esomar_url});
                }

                return europe.length ? deferred.resolve(europe) : deferred.reject(err);
            }
        });
};

var tests = {
    t1: function (dir) {
        landingPage(dir)
            .then(function (r) {
                console.log(r);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `return` before `Uni.get`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, that would return the Unirest Request object, which is not a promise (it does not expose the `then` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main function *landingPage* is not returning a value. The code inside it produces a promise, but you should also return it.

As you want to return the promise held by *deferred*, you should make *deferred* a variable that is defined in the outer function scope, so you can return the promise defined by it (`deferred.promise`):

```
var landingPage = function (dir) {
    var deferred = Q.defer(); // *** define here
    Uni.get('https://'+getDirectory(dir).url)
        .header('Content-Type','text/html')
        .end(function (lp_data) {
            var europe = []; // *** define here, before the `if`
            if (lp_data.raw_body) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(lp_data.raw_body),
                    cn_europe = $('#location_europe .list-countries li'),
                    cn_asia = $('#content-location_asia_pacific li'),
                    cn_north_america = $('#content-location_north_america li');

                // Get Europe Company List
                for (var i = 0; i < cn_europe.length; i++) {
                    var country_name = $(cn_europe[i]).find('a').html().split('(')[0].trim(),
                        esomar_url = 'https://' + getDirectory(dir).url + '/' + $(cn_europe[i]).find('a').attr('href');
                    europe.push({country_name: country_name, esomar_url: esomar_url});
                }
            }
            // *** Move this out of the above `if`, so you always resolve/reject:
            return europe.length ? deferred.resolve(europe) : deferred.reject(err);
        });
    // *** return the promise (it will not be resolved yet, but that is the idea):
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

However, there is a request to support promises in Unirest (see [here](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-nodejs/pull/60)), which allows you to do this:

```
var landingPage = function (dir) {
    // return the promise that will now come from this chain:
    return Uni.get('https://'+getDirectory(dir).url)
        .header('Content-Type','text/html')
        .end()
        .exec() // turn request object to a promise
        .then(function (lp_data) {
            var europe = []; // *** define here, before the `if`
            if (lp_data.raw_body) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(lp_data.raw_body),
                    cn_europe = $('#location_europe .list-countries li'),
                    cn_asia = $('#content-location_asia_pacific li'),
                    cn_north_america = $('#content-location_north_america li');

                // Get Europe Company List
                for (var i = 0; i < cn_europe.length; i++) {
                    var country_name = $(cn_europe[i]).find('a').html().split('(')[0].trim(),
                        esomar_url = 'https://' + getDirectory(dir).url + '/' + $(cn_europe[i]).find('a').attr('href');
                    europe.push({country_name: country_name, esomar_url: esomar_url});
                }
            }
            // *** Return the data. Throw an error if to be rejected
            if (!europe.length) throw "no data!!";
            return europe;
        });
}
```

This way you do not have to do the conversion to a promise yourself with a `deferred` object.

Comment: I did so but then again i receive `undefined` is not a function

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it/

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum, I know the anti-pattern, but where is the promise in the Request object from Unirest? Can you provide the info? NB: look at the history of my answer and the comment made.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I added a section on upcoming promise-support in Unirest, but without it, there is no other way then to create a promise and have it resolve in the `end` callback. Do I miss something?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.. It worked finally after defining the `deferred` variable out of Unirest scope... @trincot